# Without using Thread.Join() , how can i achive same functionality

Tags: java, multithreading

We are having two thread J1 and J2. How can we make sure that thread J2 run only after J1 has completed its execution without using `join()` method.

Comment: why don't you want to use `.join` ?

Comment: Take a look at [`java.util.concurrent.Exchanger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html).

Comment: You can use a `java.util.concurrent` synchronizer: CountDownLatch, Semaphore, Lock, it depends on your usecase.

Comment: @Alnitak - one possibility is that OP's thread isn't actually "done" and so he's looking for a way to get `.join` like behavior without needing to wait until the other thread terminates.

Comment: Start J2 as the last line of code in J1?

Answer (score 4):

Simple, use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Initialize the `CountDownLatch` to 1 in the `main()`. Pass it to both J1 and J2. J2 simply waits for the Latch to become 0 using `await()`. J2 sets it to 0 once done using `countDown()`, signalling J1 to start.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of working even when you can't use `.join()` (when the other thread has more work to do after both threads synchronize, and therefore won't terminate).  You can use it both in place of `.join()` and where `.join()` isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very close to what Thread.join is doing

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread t = new Thread();
        synchronized (t) {
            t.start();
            while (t.isAlive()) {
                t.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

note the magic - something wakes up t.wait() - this is because JVM notifies the Thread object when it terminates

Comment: I quite like this solution. I would prefer a `Lock` and `Condition` based approach however.

Comment: If you liked the first solution then see the second one it is really how join works

Comment: Haha, +1. If you can't use the `Thread.join` method then copy paste it into your own method.

Comment: Right :) but there's a trick - JVM interrupts the thread when finished, this is how the whole thing works

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is using  [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

```
   class X {
         private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
          // ...

         public void m() { 
           lock.lock();  // block until condition holds
           try {
              // ... method body
          } finally {
               lock.unlock()
          }
        }
   }
```